# How to move data into a cache before it is accessed

Tags: c++, caching, memory, profiling

After profiling my cpp code using callgrind, I found cache miss in some parts. Due to cache miss, the time taken by the function keeps varying and I want a nearly steady graph.

I tried using `_mm_prefetch`, however that didn't forced the data into cache.
I know this is not a good practice and also modern compilers perform pre-fetching. But is there a way through which I can force the data to be in cache (Either through programming or an assembly code). I want to see the effect on my code after pre-fetching.

My CPU is:

- Model name : Intel (R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
- Cache size : 8MB

Comment: As far as I know, no data can be forced into the cache. The compiler and the program can only provide **hints** to pre-fetch. Cache is fully transparent to the OS, so there is no way a program can **enforce** data into the cache. Please have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558217/force-some-data-on-l1-cache